# I have a custom font for my website that looks fine on desktop but will change to the default font on iphone and android. How to prevent this?

Tags: fonts, web-frontend, mobile-website

I have a custom font for my website that looks fine on desktop (Chrome) but will change to the/a default font on Safari, Firefox, iphone/android. How do I fix this? (CSS HTML)

Can't find the right words since I keep getting bug results for default fonts instead of how to solve for this... Please help.

Comment: Thank you so much @SiKing  I do not know how to upvote a comment!

Comment: Don't worry about comments. Just upvote questions / answers that you find useful. :)